# writing python 3.6 on mac, want to use pip to install packages but pip uses python 2.7, creates problems

Tags: pip, package, python-3.6

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I want to use the pygame package for something I'm writing in python 3.6 . I want to use pip or pip3 to install but it seems not to work and I suspect its because when I input:

'pip --version'

into terminal, it returns:

'pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)'.

Is there a way to make the path .../python3.6/...? Also, as a beginner, if anyone could help me understand how to best manage the location of all these packages in my system I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

This type of question arises often. There are several program/files/paths involved here.

1. `pip` is a program. You can find its location by typing `which pip`. Ideally, `pip` is in the same prefix (i.e. `/usr`, `/usr/local`, `/home/user/mycustomprefix` or `/home/user/.local`, for instance) as `python`. This is not mandatory however and can cause confusion.
2. `pip` calls code that is in a Python package named `pip` and that is displayed by `pip --version`.
3. when `pip` is run, it will look for the `pip` package and will find whatever comes first in Python's `sys.path`.

There is a "safe" mechanism to invoke the pip that is related to a given `python`, `python2` or `python3` interpreter. In your situation, the interpreter will be named `python3` or `python3.6`. Instead of `pip`, run

```
python3 -m pip install PACKAGENAME
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install --user PACKAGENAME
```

This will install the package in a prefix that is available to the given interpreter.

Comment: Great thanks for the response! If you don't mind me asking another related question, where would a smart programmer keep these files? If I have for example, the directories: 'Downloads', 'Documents', 'Library', and 'python' (this is where I keep all my code and projects), would you recommend keeping the packages in python? At the moment packages install to Library by default which I suspect is causing the problem. Although matplotlib and this package are in the same location inside Library but matplotlib works just fine! Thanks again!

Comment: The standard locations where installed packages are found are, in general `/usr/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` (where `X` and `Y` are the major, 2 or 3, and the minor version of Python) for the package manager installed packages and `~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` for user-installed packages. Unless you have a specific reason, there is no motivation to make this more complex.